# Reviewing your own first post

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, private-beta

Today I became a member of the (private-beta) Sustainable Living site. I answered a few questions and then noticed that I could already use the review function (rep still at 101). 
While reviewing first posts I came across one of my own answers. I guess this is a bug?

Comment: Just tested on a beta site myself and I don't have access to the Reviews option. Navigating directly to /review shows that I can't access any of the items - at minimum I need 125 rep *"You need at least 125 reputation to review First Posts."* so yes, looks like a bug to me (although I haven't actually answered / asked anything on there unlike yourself so that may be the variable)

Comment: It's little moments like these that make Meta such a wonderful coffee companion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is fixed now. You shouldn't get your *own* post in the First Posts or Late Answers review queues any more.