# Review your own post?

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, 10k-tools, duplicate-answers

The sequence of events were the following:

- I answered a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131641/5764).
- At the time of posting, I noticed a comment directing to a [duplicate post source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129893/5764).
- Rather than keeping my answer under the (newly posted) duplicate, I deleted it and posted it under the duplicate source.

After a while, I noticed my [visible answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131649/5764) came up as an automated flag under the [10K-tools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tools). This doesn't seem appropriate since, well, I'm biased and all...

[image]

Related: [Reviewing your own first post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165557/168244)